# Pushing the next item to forward

Tags: html, css

how to  push the next item to the right when I click on any item have

slider-item class ?

i use **transform:trnslateX**() But it does not push and Puts on the next

item!
and  can't use margin and padding either
...

If you have any other way, help me
thanks

```html
<div class=" col-12 slider-holder d-flex flex-nowrap flex-row justify-content-between">


  <div class="item-holder col mx-auto overflow d-flex flex-row flex-nowrap justify-content-between ">
    <!--Slider Item-->
    <div class="slider-item">
      <figure>
        <img src="css/img/keshmesh.png" alt="asda">
      </figure>
    </div>
    <!--Slider Item-->


    <!--Slider Item-->
    <div class="slider-item">
      <figure>
        <img src="css/img/keshmesh.png" alt="asda">
      </figure>
    </div>
    <!--Slider Item-->



    <!--Slider Item-->
    <div class="slider-item">
      <figure>
        <img src="css/img/keshmesh.png" alt="asda">
      </figure>
    </div>
    <!--Slider Item-->



    <!--Slider Item-->
    <div class="slider-item">
      <figure>
        <img src="css/img/keshmesh.png" alt="asda">
      </figure>
    </div>
    <!--Slider Item-->




    <!--Slider Item-->
    <div class="slider-item">
      <figure>
        <img src="css/img/keshmesh.png" alt="asda">
      </figure>
    </div>
    <!--Slider Item-->
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what the expected outcome and behaviour is?

Answer (score 1):

Normally clicks are listened to via javascript, using the following event listener:

```
myElement.addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
```

If, instead, you want to listen to a click via CSS, you can achieve this by adding

```
tabindex="0"
```

to the element's markup (to make the element `focusable`) and then describing the element's presentation using the

```
:focus
```

pseudo-class.

**Working Example:**

```css
.slider-item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 136px;
  height: 136px;
  padding: 12px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}

.slider-item:focus {

  transform: translateX(200px);
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="0" class="slider-item">
Click me and<br />I will slide to the right
</div>
```